# Callback function confuses argument?

Tags: c++, callback, containers, sfml

I have a sfml window container, and it appears to be working, however the glViewPorts are the wrong size, which I assume is because the wrong sf::Window is being passed.

Here is a function which adds to the window: It takes some information about the sfml window.

```
int WindowContainer::PushBack(WindowData& data)
{
    if(data.WindowSettingsOK() && data.VideoModeOK()){

        mWindowVector.resize(mWindowVector.size() + 1);
        mDisplayFuncVector.resize(mWindowVector.size());
        mInputFuncVector.resize(mWindowVector.size());

        mWindowVector.at(mWindowVector.size() - 1) = new sf::Window();
        mWindowVector.at(mWindowVector.size() - 1)->Create(data.VideoMode(), data.Title(), data.Style(), data.Settings());
        mWindowVector.at(mWindowVector.size() - 1)->SetPosition(data.PositionX(), data.PositionY());

        mDisplayFuncVector.at(mWindowVector.size() - 1) = nullptr;
        mInputFuncVector.at(mWindowVector.size() - 1) = nullptr;

        return 0;
    }
    else{
        PrintError(ErrorMessageType::BadSettings);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, this function may be called to setup the display and input function callbacks:

```
int WindowContainer::PushBack(WindowData& data, function_p displayFunc, function_p inputFunc)
{
    int return_val = PushBack(data);
    mDisplayFuncVector.at(mWindowVector.size() - 1) = displayFunc;
    mInputFuncVector.at(mWindowVector.size() - 1) = inputFunc;

    return return_val;
}
```

Then, when the window needs `.Display()`'ing, this function is called:

```
void WindowContainer::ProcessDisplay()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mWindowVector.size(); i ++){
        if(mDisplayFuncVector.at(i) != nullptr){
            mDisplayFuncVector.at(i)(*mWindowVector.at(i), mClock, (const void*&)mExternalDrawingDataPointer);
        }
        mWindowVector.at(i)->Display();
    }
}
```

... This is all good, until the result on the screen is that resizing one window affects the viewport of both windows. This suggests that calling the callback function: `mDisplayFuncVector.at(i)(*mWindowVector.at(i), mClock, (const void*&)mExternalDrawingDataPointer);` gives the argument of `*mWindowVector.at(0)` each time, instead of each window individually. (As in `*mWindowVector.at(i)`)

Can anyone help with this problem?

The main loop contains this code:

```
while(container.Access(0)->IsOpened()){
    container.ProcessInput();
    container.ProcessDisplay();
}
```

`Container.Access(int)` is this function:

```
const sf::Window*& WindowContainer::Access(unsigned int index)
{
    if(index > mWindowVector.size()){
        PrintError(ErrorMessageType::IndexOutOfRange);
    }
    else{
        return (const sf::Window*&)mWindowVector.at(index);
    }
    return (const sf::Window*&)mWindowVector.at(0);
}
```

Thanks again, I'm sure I have made a mistake somewhere but cannot spot it.

Comment: What's the prototype for your display function?

Comment: Inside main.cpp I have this function:


`void display(sf::Window& window, const sf::Clock& clock, const void*& data);`

Is that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been thinking about this question and suspect openGL becomes confused with which window is it drawing to if more than one object is pushed back without a call to Display() to sync everything.

I am yet to test this and confirm.

**EDIT** The window container now works. It has nothing to do with the callback functions argument.

Comment: Maybe you could post what the problem was and the solution you found for other people with a similar problem.

Comment: A good idea, however I think it may be too specific to be worth posting.

I suspect it has something to do with the way sfml windows work, but I cannot be sure.